# Auto-reload page only if textbox is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to reload my page every 10 seconds, unless someone is typing into the textbox on the page. Obviously, I don't want to refresh while the user is typing.

I know I can reload the page by doing:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.reload(1);
}, 10000);
```

And I thought I could check to see if there is any value in the input, but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    if ($("input").val == null) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.reload(1);
        }, 10000);
    }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Once the user has input something in the input, do you want to disable the reloading permanently? For example, if they finish typing and focus leaves the input, what happens?

Comment: There is only one text area for this page, so once they have finished typing, they will submit which will reload the page anyway, so yes. It should loop and continue to look to see if the field is empty or not. Not sure if `.val` is the correct method for this.

Comment: Okay - that makes sense. See my answer for an alternative approach which is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a timeout, you can assign it to a variable, which you can then cancel with `clearTimeout`, like so:

```
// Set the timeout to a variable to reference later
var pageReloader = setTimeout(function(){
      window.location.reload(1);
    }, 10000),
   // This function checks if the value in the input is different to the one at page load. If it has changed, stop the refresh
    checkInputDirty = function(event){
      if (event.target.value != event.target.defaultValue) {
        clearTimeout(pageReloader);
      }
    },
    userInput = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');

//Add listeners to keyup and change events.
userInput.addEventListener('keyup', checkInputDirty);
userInput.addEventListener('change', checkInputDirty);
```

The advantage of this method is that you can stop checking once the input has changed, rather than firing the timeout, checking the value every 10 seconds for the life of the page.

Checking against the default value is more robust than just checking if it's empty. If the user has typed and then deletes their text in the field, they may still be in the process of editing, but the refresh will happen anyway. Checking against the default value also allows you to set your own default value if you ever need to.

Sorry - I only just noticed you were using jQuery, you could do:

```
var pageReloader = setTimeout(function(){
      window.location.reload(1);
    });

$('input[type=text]').on('keyup change', function(input){
  if (this.val() != this[0].defaultValue) { //jQuery doesn't expose default value directly, so get it from the DOM node
    clearTimeout(pageReloader);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One issue with your solution is this line:

```
if ($("input").val == null) { ...
```

In jQuery `.val` is actually a method. Try calling it as a method  instead:

```
if (!$("input").val()) { ...
```

Also note the use of `!` before `$("input").val()`. In jQuery, an input with no value returns an empty string.

Empty strings are considered 'falsey' in JavaScript - roughly equivalent to `false`. By negating a falsey value, the `if` condition in your code will be satisfied when the input field is empty

A complete solution might be as simple as this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if (!$("input").val()) {
        window.location.reload(1);
    }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: You should also mention that '' will evaluate as false.

Answer (score 1):

Here's modified code and its comment.

First, if you mean the distinct input, you should use jQuery selector accurately to select it, like `$('#input')` or `$('input:eq(0)')`.

Second, use `!$('#input').val()` to check. Because if jQuery selector selected no element, the `val()` function return `undefined` instead of `''` empty string.

if there's any question please let me know.

```js
// setInterval should fit your situation.
var timeout = setInterval(function() {
    //if ($("input").val == null) {    
    // check if the input value is falsy, note that $().val is a function
    if (!$("input").val()) {
        // you checked the value per 10 seconds, no need to wait another 10 seconds when you checked the value is falsy.
        // setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.reload(1);
            // you'd better pass boolean value to location.reload(), like window.location.reload(true). Code above works too so don't worry.
        // }, 10000);
    }
}, 10000);

// if user key in anything, then clearInterval to stop checking value
$(document).on('input.input', 'input', function(){
  clearInterval(timeout);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
```

Comment: This still does the same thing, it reloads the page. But it does not stop if something had been typed into the input. Is there a better way to do it, e.g. an onChange event?

Comment: When user's typing, after timeout for 10 seconds and do checking, input should has value and not go into and won't trigger reload.